# javascript interface keyword in the react-native codebase

Tags: javascript

I'm looking at some code from the react-native codebase (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/bac2c2c80158a654be947d43a3fbd75d5cb1395a/Libraries/Components/ScrollView/ScrollViewCommands.js) and I don't understand the syntax and I can't find a reference to it. The file is .js but javascript does not have a interface keyword. Can someone tell what flavor of javascript that is and who/what supports it? Thanks

```
interface NativeCommands {
  +flashScrollIndicators: (
    viewRef: React.ElementRef<ScrollViewNativeComponentType>,
  ) => void;
  +scrollTo: (
    viewRef: React.ElementRef<ScrollViewNativeComponentType>,
    x: Double,
    y: Double,
    animated: boolean,
  ) => void;
  ....   


export default (codegenNativeCommands<NativeCommands>({
 supportedCommands: [
   'flashScrollIndicators',
   'scrollTo',
   'scrollToEnd',
   'zoomToRect',
 ],
}): NativeCommands);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not TypeScript, but [flow](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/interfaces/), a static type-checking system for JavaScript. (the `@flow strict-local` is a hint) It's similar to TS, but they're not the same thing.

Yes, flow [can be written in `.js` files](https://flow.org/en/docs/declarations/#:%7E:text=flow%20extension%20applies%20both%20to,js%20files%20as%20well%20as%20.&text=js.,flow%20and%20.), despite the content not being JavaScript syntax. It's a bit confusing. ([discussion here](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4233))

An [interface](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/interfaces/) indicates the *type shape* of an object. Inside an interface, for example, `+flashScrollIndicators:` means that that property on the object is [read-only](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/interfaces/#toc-interface-property-variance-read-only-and-write-only).

Comment: do you know what it compiles down to (I'm assuming, similar to TypeScript, it will compile down to javascript)?

Comment: what would `codegenNativeCommands<NativeCommands>(...)` compile down to?

Comment: It's a [generic function](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/bac2c2c80158a654be947d43a3fbd75d5cb1395a/Libraries/Utilities/codegenNativeCommands.js#L17), and [see here](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/) generics allow you to essentially pass *type arguments* in addition to standard JS arguments. Interfaces can be generic too. Eg `Array<string>` produces the type of an array which contains strings, by passing `string` as a type parameter to the Array interface.

Comment: That particular line will compile down to `export default codegenNativeCommands({ supportedCommands: ['...'] });`